# Wordpress mysterious elements (<p>, <a>) shows up on live site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

first time developing a website on Wordpress and mucking about on my home page to make it looks better. I ran into a problem when trying to wrap my `div` with `a` to make the entire box clickable/link.

in page editing code looks like this:

```
<a href="random_link1">
  <div>
    <img src="random_image1"/><br>
    random text 1
  </div>
</a>
<a href="random_link2">
  <div>
    <img src="random_image2"/><br>
    random text 2
  </div>
</a>
```

And there are multiple divs in a row like this that is supposed to be side by side (using css display: inline-block)

But then the live site would have these divs stack vertically. Upon examining using developer tools (chrome), I find the code to turn up extra `p` element with the exact same `a` in the middle of the divs:

```
<a href="random_link1">
  <div>
    <img src="random_image1"/><br>
    random text 1
  </div>
</a>
<p>
  <a href="random_link1"></a>
  <a href="random_link2"></a>
</p>
<a href="random_link2">
  <div>
    <img src="random_image2"/><br>
    random text 2
  </div>
</a>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress automatically runs a filter on your content, called `wpautop`. It's used to transform carriage returns from editor into html spacing. You can remove it globally using `functions.php`

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

...or look for a plugin that enables you more fine-grained control over what gets autop-ed and what not.

Additionally, you have the option of hiding empty `<p>` tags:

```
p:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

The same filter (`wpautop`) wraps your links into `<p>` elements. The solution is to either:

- wrap your `<a>` tags into `<div>` tags, or...
- run your own filter on `content`, undoing what `wpautop` did, after `wpautop`. See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/stop-wordpress-wrapping-images-in-a-p-tag).

Comment: I'd love to know the reason for down-vote, so I can learn from my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you for your reply and good guidance! I've opted to install the "toggle wpautop" plugin as the problem is specific to my home page. On the other hand, I imagine I will muck around with `functions.php` in the future as it seems to mess around a lot with the kind of control you would hope for when web developing. So, to sum it up, thanks!